# Decision between BIOS and UEFI

Tags: operating-system, osdev

I recently decided to start a OS development project for learning purpose. Right now I have run into trouble deciding between two interfaces(system? What should I refer them as?). One of the major difference I figured was that the way of implementing graphics. In BIOS one could use VESA video mode while in UEFI one could directly write in the framebuffer. Are there any difference between them efficiency wise? If I decide to use UEFI, is there any other way to implement the graphics efficiently while not being impossible for a indi dev(e.g. writing a driver for gpu)?

Personally, I consider this project as a very long-term-expandable-time-killer project. I know writing graphic interface is very time consuming but I also enjoy that process. I don't want to remake the kernel due to some mistakes in decisions I made in the early stage of the development.

Comment: I'd suggest skipping graphics. Instead, use the PC standard IO space serial ports to create a console/shell. It also has the advantage of not being tied to the memory map.

Comment: personally, I consider this project as a very long-term-expandable-time-killer project. I know writing graphic interface is very time consuming but I also enjoy that process. I don't want to remake the kernel due to some mistakes in decisions I made in the early stage of the development? Any idea on the efficiency on the two system?

Comment: Why not do both, if you have time.  That way, you can have a mechanism (vesa) which works everywhere, and a more optimal one (fb) which works on properly configured systems.  wxWizard’s advice is good, and should be heeded for another reason: a single opcode can produce useful status ( write to character memory ) when you are debugging your os, with no interrupt and little timing disruption.  This is a huge advantage writing kernels.